# Can I ask a question about PHP hacking of osCommerce here?

Tags: discussion

First a little background of where I'm coming from. I'm trying to set up osCommerce (an open-source ecommerce solution) with a little tweakings on the minimum amount of items that customers can order. For that I need a very specific and minute change in a PHP file (osCommerce is almost entirely PHP). I know what I need to do, but due to my inexperience in web programming (or any programming languages for that matter, I don't know how to implement it).

Now since the issue is related to CMSes I first went Pro Webmasters, and the FAQ stated that programming questions were dealt with on StackOverflow. This is where the niche issue comes in - it's just a tiny tweak I want to ask about - I'm not sure if it will fit in to the programming nature of the SE. And to top it off, I feel uncomfortable to ask question for commercial interests, even if I'm just helping dad out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asking a question because it's backed by a commercial interest is completely reasonable.  I'd wager that the majority of questions on Stack Overflow are related directly to a person's commercial interests because it directly relates to a task they have on hand at their job.

If the tweak is programattic, then it's completely *on topic* for Stack Overflow.  However, the general guidelines about question quality still apply; just because it's a question involving programming doesn't mean that it should be a crap question about programming.

Also, if your question spams the hell out of your product, it will be looked down upon and more than likely dealt with in some manner, but I get the feeling there won't be a need to mention/link to your product specifically (not that you can't, but if it's not directly related to the question at hand, it's generally not a good idea).

Of course, you can put almost anything you want in your profile, so if you wanted to promote your product, that would be the place to do it.

Remember, if you're contributing quality content (and that means quality questions) to *any* site on the Stack Exchange network, that's a *good thing*.

Comment: Nothing to worry about there, the question has nothing to do with any specific product. The shop isn't even production ready, so other than sample products provided by the CMS, there's nothing to spam about. :P

Comment: I've posted the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959638/require-minimum-number-of-items-to-checkout-on-oscommerce), though it received two or more downvotes for unknown reasons. If anyone reads this comment and think you know why, please comment on my question!